# How to delete parts of an object which are transparent in its image texture?

Tags: texturing

I want to delete the black parts of this head object. There is nothing there it is transparent.
I want it to look like it does in the texture paint mode so i can just put the face on the other head.

Here is a video
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKXD9.jpg

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rrq6Wt_44W68tpk1aewl-IiEyokSF85g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: heres the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rrq6Wt_44W68tpk1aewl-IiEyokSF85g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

in your material, just plug in alpha to alpha like so:

[image]

and in your material change blend mode to "alpha blend".

[image]

Then you get (in rendered mode) this:

[image]